# Dividing my page in 2 vertical columns (html or css)

Tags: html, css, layout

It's the first time I design a website so I need help with dividing my page into 2 vertical parts.

Basically, I want to have this page : http://elishaabargel.com/denim and this page http://elishaabargel.com/denim2 combined. I mean that I want the flash animation on the left and the links  to the technical drawings and sketches on the right, down on the page.

The first page already contains the html and css codes of the right part but it just doesn't appear.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did this in a bit of a rush, and im sure some bits are incorrect like the alignment of your pics on the right being at the top rather than the bottom also the popups are not the same size as your original popups... But it does fix your original issue of the two panels.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title>Elisha Bargel</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="keywords" content="fashion, design, student, shenkar, college, portfolio, creation, mode">
<meta name="description" content="Fashion designer Elisha Abargel: projects, pictures, contact.">
<style type="text/css">
    #flashContent { width:100%; height:100%; }
    body {background-color: #FFFFFF;}
    h1 {font-family:Cursive; color: #000000;}
    p {font-family:Cursive; font-size: 14pt; font-style: normal; font-weight: normal; color: #000000;}
    .link {color: #000000;}
    .alink {color: #000000;}
    .vlink {color: #000000;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <div id="MainTitle" style="text-align: center;"><img alt="" src="http://elishaabargel.com/photos/logo2.jpg"></div>
        <div id="MainLinks" style="text-align: center;"><a href="http://elishaabargel.com/projects.html" style="font-size: 3; font-family: 'courier new'; text-decoration: none;">projects</a> - <a href="http://elishaabargel.com/contact.html" style="font-size: 3; font-family: 'courier new'; text-decoration: none;">contact</a></div>
        <div id="LeftPanel" style="width: 800; height: 100%; float: left;">
            <h1>Denim Project</h1>
            <div id="flashContent">
                <object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" width="800" height="612" id="denimproject" align="middle">
                    <param name="movie" value="http://elishaabargel.com/photos/flashgalleries/denimproject.swf" />
                    <param name="quality" value="high" />
                    <param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" />
                    <param name="play" value="true" />
                    <param name="loop" value="true" />
                    <param name="wmode" value="window" />
                    <param name="scale" value="showall" />
                    <param name="menu" value="true" />
                    <param name="devicefont" value="false" />
                    <param name="salign" value="" />
                    <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
                    <!--[if !IE]>-->
                    <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://elishaabargel.com/photos/flashgalleries/denimproject.swf" width="800" height="612">
                        <param name="movie" value="http://elishaabargel.com/photos/flashgalleries/denimproject.swf" />
                        <param name="quality" value="high" />
                        <param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" />
                        <param name="play" value="true" />
                        <param name="loop" value="true" />
                        <param name="wmode" value="window" />
                        <param name="scale" value="showall" />
                        <param name="menu" value="true" />
                        <param name="devicefont" value="false" />
                        <param name="salign" value="" />
                        <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
                    <!--<![endif]-->
                        <a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflash">
                            <img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash player" />
                        </a>
                    <!--[if !IE]>-->
                    </object>
                    <!--<![endif]-->
                </object>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div id="RightPanel" style="width: 200; height: 100%; text-align: left; vertical-align: bottom; float: right;">
            <a href="http://elishaabargel.files.wordpress.com/2012/12/sketchesdenim.jpg" target="_blank"><img alt="technical drawings of the denim project" style="width: 349px; height: 150px; vertical-align: bottom;" src="http://elishaabargel.files.wordpress.com/2012/12/sketchesdenim.jpg"></a><br />
            <a href="http://elishaabargel.files.wordpress.com/2012/12/technicaldrawingsdenim.jpg" target="_blank"><img alt="technical drawings of the denim project" style="width: 349px; height: 150px; vertical-align: bottom;" src="http://elishaabargel.files.wordpress.com/2012/12/technicaldrawingsdenim.jpg"></a>
        </div>
</div>
</form>
```

I'm sure yu can put your JQuery code block back to address the popups being of incorrect size.

Comment: That is great! Thank you. I will try to sort out the other issues then

Answer (score 9):

There are many ways to divide a page into two parts you could either use iframes, divs, or a table. The most simple would be a table.

```
<table width=100% height=100%><tr><td width=50%>Put page1 here</td><td width=50%>Put page2 here</td></tr></table>
```

Also if you are loading two completely full pages it might just be best to use an iframe.

```
<iframe src="pg1.html" style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:50%;height:100%;"></iframe>
<iframe src="pg2.html" style="position:absolute;top:0;left:50%;width:50%;height:100%;"></iframe>
```

Comment: @user1972861: No problem, please remember to check my solution off as the answer so others know this question was answered. Have a nice day.

Comment: Fiddle of the first option taking into account that CSS should be used  now to style the table: http://jsfiddle.net/gGyDx/4/

Comment: It is possible but shouldn't we add the disclaimer that these don't reflect best practices for html layout?

Answer (score 4):

I thought I should add the simplest template (using `div`s) that worked for me here:

```
<div id="container" style="width:100%;">                                   
  <div id="left" style="float:left; width:50%;"> This is left panel </div>                     
  <div id="right" style="float:right; width:50%;"> This is right panel </div>                   
</div>
```

You can change the css style options (like `width`) appropriately to suit your needs.

Answer (score 4):

You can use bootstrap for division of your page.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-6"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

If you need 100% width, you can use container-fluid and row-fluid.. I hope this will help you.